# The reason for connection of gate and drain in P-FET in an amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier, resistors, capacitance

[image: two-stage fully differential amplifier]

Why is there a connection between the gate and drain of PMOS by capacitor?

For CMFB, why was the capacitor used in parallel with the resistor?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is there a connection between the gate and drain of PMOS by
> capacitor?*

There is always a capacitor present even if it's just the internal parasitic drain-gate capacitor. It can have quite a quite a significant role in stabilizing an op-amp when used with high-levels of negative feedback. That could be the reason it is shown explicitly.

> *For CMFB, why was the capacitor used in parallel with the resistor?*

When you have a two-resistor potential divider where the centre-point is the common-mode voltage, you need to protect that node against external parasitic capacitance that can alter high-frequency common-mode signals. To minimize this effect, capacitors are put parallel to the potential divider resistors to ensure that the divider has a good high-frequency response.

On another note, I'd be concerned about the reliability of the source of your circuit given that the two areas in the orange boxes (I added) below are "strange" and I can't explain: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 
The circuit for compensation in the orange box is not correct. I agree with you.

Comment: @FatemehShakibaee just so you know why people give their help for free, please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).